# C# call interface method implemented in many classes without having instance to those classes

Tags: c#

###### Sample Code

```
using System;

public interface MyInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
}

public class A:MyInterface
{
    void MyInterface.MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World from A");
    }
}

public class B:MyInterface
{
    void MyInterface.MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World from B");
    }
}

public class C:MyInterface
{
    void MyInterface.MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World from C");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        C obj = new C();
        MyInterface iface=(MyInterface)obj;
        iface.MyMethod(); // This will print "Hello World from C"
    }
}
```

###### The Problem

The Sample code I given above shows the method I used for calling interface method in my project, In the code I have an interface called `MyInterface` and it has a method called `MyMethod()`, In current sample I called the interface method using object of Class `C`, In my project I will have more classes that needs to implement MyInterface and the My method in all these classes need to be called at once.

###### Take an Example

Currently I have classes A,B,C and all of them have `MyMethod()` with Different function body, then later I added another class D and I need to call `MyMethod()` in all classes at the same time, the number of classes might be 100's, so is there any way to call all `MyMethod()` without creating object for 100's of classes.

Comment: It seems to me that you are confusing the concepts of "class", "object" and "instance".
And so it is not clear from your explanations what you need to implement.
Add some additional explanation.
Hundreds of different classes or different instances?
If there are different instances, how are references to them preserved?
Is there a general collection of these instances?
Can you use a common abstract base class besides the interface?

Comment: This is not how interfaces work. Interfaces are not designed so you can call a method in one implementation, and the same method gets called in all other implementations. An interfaces is merely a contract that describes functionality implementations must provide.

Comment: i mean the interface method should be similar to a static method, which doesn't need an instance of object to call, but @David provided an alternate solution, even though it requires an instance I can add each object instance to IEnumerable so I can iterate through each one to call MyMethod().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). You can have a method like this:

```
public static void ExecuteMyMethods(IEnumerable<MyInterface> instances)
{
    foreach(var instance in instances) instance.MyMethod();
}
```

It will be working for you as needed and you will not have to modify it when new implementation of MyInterface occurs. You will have to pass the new instance from the caller side.

You can also wrap & isolate the logic of getting the collection of *MyInterface* implementations somewhere, to have it in a single place & once new implementation comes around, you will know where to create an instance of it, for this method to work properly. You can consider using [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for that.