# Is there a more effective generic way of achieving this?

Tags: c#

Just wondering if there is a more generic way of achieving the following:

```
public class Payment
{}

public class Paypal : Payment
{
public string PaypalKey{get;set;}
}

public class WorldPay : Payment
{
public int WorldPayID{get;set;}
}

public class PaymentService
{
    public PaymentResponse Process(Payment payment)
    {
        //Checking payment type and casting to access properties as they differ on each payment
        if (payment is WorldPay) //cast to WorldPay
        if (payment is Paypal) //cast to Paypal
        //Perform logic to build a response for given payment and return the response
        return paymentResponse;
    }
}
```

Each payment type can have own properties and finding that checking and casting is becoming a bit messy. Just wondering if there is a cleaner way.

The idea is the caller of Process can pass in the payment type giving only properties that are required for that payment.  Could make it generic but that would mean properties would need to be optional.

The Process method will return the response to the user.  The response will be created based on on the input method and will contain various properties based on the input payment.

Comment: What kind of properties and why do you need to access them explicitly? Can you not handle them via virtual functions directly in the derived classes themselves?

Comment: Add an abstract `Process()` method to class `Payment`, and implement it (via override) in derived classes. Then just call `payment.Process()` from `PaymentService`.

Comment: Its hard to answer this question, at this stage there is no need for generics, no need for inheritance, and no need for a process function. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` There is not much to work with here.

Comment: Payment like Paypal/Worldpay are more like DTO's so each has properties that the other might not so having a process() method would not help.

Comment: Depending on what you will do in the if statements there are a lot of ways to solve this including overriding methods, working with generics, and so on... what do you need to accomplish?

Comment: @TheGeneral you are right generic Process<T> is another option but again still need to cast the type back to derived type to gain access to its properties.

Comment: Since you stated that `Payment` itself is just a DTO and you want to have the `Process()` logic in the `PaymentService` could you implement generic PaymentServices that share the same base class / interface. If you use DI you could resolve each service for the given payment type.

Comment: I think this can be more of a design issue. Based on the information you provided in the question, it's natural to think that *polymorphism* will solve your problem, since having "Process" method in your classes is totally okay. But since you say that those models are DTOs, hence only have some information in the properties a question arrises to me why do you use those in your `PaymentService`? I'd cast those to business models & then run business logic.

Comment: If you can't have `Process` method in you models, maybe it's worth having smth like `GetVerificationDetails` in your models that will return a common model for all the payment types and you can use that model for your further needs?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think we can help you, till you provide more details on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69334057/c-sharp-call-interface-method-implemented-in-many-classes-without-having-instanc/69334210#69334210) to a similar question.

What you can do is to use polymorphism. Just declare a *virtual* or *abstract* method *"Process"* in the parent class *"Payment"* and override that method in each concrete sub-type.
And just execute that method in your *"PaymentService"*

```
public class Payment
{
   // Common properties & staff

   public abstract/virtual void Process();
}

public class Paypal : Payment
{
   public override void Process() 
   { 
       // Paypal implementation 
   }
}

public class WorldPay : Payment
{
   public override void Process() 
   { 
       // WorldPay implementation 
   }
}

public class PaymentService
{
    public void Process(Payment payment)
    {
        payment.Process();    
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't help payment is more of a DTO and will return a different result depending on its type.

Comment: In that case you need to provide more details on what you have. What you mean by *"will return a different result depending on its type"* ? Can you please provide more information on that? Because I am afraid you may have a design issue there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid putting actual payment processing code in the DTOs ***and*** you want to make the `PaymentService` generic, then you could do something like this:

```
public class PaymentService
{
    private List<(Type type, Delegate process)> _processes = new List<(Type, Delegate)>();

    public void Register<T>(Func<T, PaymentResponse> process) where T : Payment
    {
        _processes.Add((typeof(T), (Func<Payment, PaymentResponse>)(p => process((T)p))));
    }

    public PaymentResponse Process(Payment payment) =>
        _processes
            .Where(p => p.type.IsAssignableFrom(payment.GetType()))
            .Select(p => (Func<Payment, PaymentResponse>)p.process)
            .Concat(new Func<Payment, PaymentResponse>[] { p => null })
            .First()
            .Invoke(payment);
}
```

Now, to demo, here's my code:

```
public class PaymentResponse
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public PaymentResponse(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }
}   

void Main()
{
    var paymentService = new PaymentService();
    paymentService.Register<WorldPay>(p => new PaymentResponse("WorldPay!"));
    paymentService.Register<Paypal>(p => new PaymentResponse("Paypal!"));
    
    var payment = new Paypal();
    
    var response = paymentService.Process(payment);
    
    Console.WriteLine(response.Message);
}
```

When I run that code I get `Paypal!` on the console.

This kind of code allows you to inject in the behaviour into `PaymentService` in a strongly-typed way.

Answer (score -1):

it would be preferable to use an interface.

```
public interface IPayment
{
   Process();
}

public class Paypal : IPayment
{
   Process() { //do stuff }
}

public class WorldPay : IPayment
{
   Process() { //do stuff }
}

public class PaymentService
{
    public void Process(IPayment payment)
    {
        payment.Process();    
    }
}
```

That way you can mock that interface if you wanted to write unit tests and you remove the dependency of PaymentService on the base Payment class.

Comment: please explain the downvote otherwise its not really very helpful

Answer (score -1):

Given the context, given in comments, that these payment types should be DTOs without behaviours, I'd suggest you use `dynamic` so you don't have to test the different types<sup>1</sup>:

```
public class PaymentService
{
    public void Process(Payment payment)
    {
        ProcessInternal(payment as dynamic);
    }

    private void ProcessInternal(WorldPay payment)
    {
        //Do WorldPay stuff
    }

    private void ProcessInternal(Paypal payment)
    {
        //Do paypal stuff
    }
}
```

Note that (as with your type testing code), you need to consider what happens when a new type is added. Using either my code above, by default, you'd get a runtime error.

If there is a sensible way to handle new types without needing to type test, include a `ProcessInternal(Payment payment)` method which can then act as the "fallback" when a more specific match isn't made.

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, behind the scenes type checks are happening, but you don't have to write that code yourself.

Comment: Yes dynamic is one way.  Regarding when a new method is added this can be handled in many ways like controlled from database and reflection etc.  But read somewhere use dynamic sparingly as developers might get confused on what they need to put  in the call.

Comment: @AliK - we're only using `dynamic` inside this `PaymentService` class to get runtime dispatching to the right method. Callers still only see one method they can call (`Process`) that is still just accepting a `Payment` instance.